# How do I set breakpoint in Eclipse in a Target Platform JAR?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jar, breakpoints, target-platform

I need to set breakpoint in Eclipse in a Target Platform JAR.
The JAR does not appear in Package Explorer.
Is it possible?

Comment: Breakpoints are not set on files but on class-names and line numbers and transmitted into the JVM when the debugger connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Despite the accuracy of +Robert's comment, setting a breakpoint must be done through the UI, and that's only possible when the relevant class is in the Package Explorer or open in an editor.